# Android Game Programming by Example книга Джона Нортона - не пойму вычисление границы

Tags: java, android

В книге Джона Нортона "Android Game Programming by Example" на 120 стр. автор проверяет попадает ли объект на экран или не попадает. Для это пишет метод

```
public boolean clipObjects(float objectX, float objectY, float objectWidth, float objectHeight) {

 boolean clipped = true;
 if (objectX - objectWidth <
 currentViewportWorldCentre.x + (metresToShowX / 2)) {

 if (objectX + objectWidth >
 currentViewportWorldCentre.x - (metresToShowX / 2)) {

 if (objectY - objectHeight <
 currentViewportWorldCentre.y +
 (metresToShowY / 2)) {

 if (objectY + objectHeight >
 currentViewportWorldCentre.y -
 (metresToShowY / 2)){
clipped = false;
 }
 }
 }
 }
 return clipped;
}
```

Первые два "if" проверяют попадание по X, следующие два по Y.
Я понимаю как работает 2-ой "if" - т.е. если левый край объекта находится левее экрана, но объект длинный и правый край объекта всё-таки дотягивается до экрана. Значит он будет видим. Тут понятно.
Но 1-ый "if"? Если левый край объекта вышел за правый край экрана, то ширина объекта не имеет никакого значения. Зачем использовать её в вычислении? Тот же самый вопрос возникает и по оси Y. Или я что-то не так понял?

Comment: Да там ошибка,1 и 3 должны быть без вычитания. Но ошибка не критическая, просто будут выводиться невидимые объекты затрачивая машинное время.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, что objectX - центр, а objectWidth- полуширина. Тогда

```
если левый край объекта левее правого края окна
  и если правый край объекта правее левого края окна
     и по Y 
        то в окно попадает
```

Можно все условия и логику комбинирования (и/или) инвертировать, это кажется более очевидным:

```
если левый край правее правого края окна
   или если правый край объекта левее левого края окна
       то ясно, что НЕ попадает
```

Comment: нет objectX это левый край, а objectWidth- ширина. Я предполагаю, что там ошибка, но может я чего-то не понял

Comment: Да, действительно, перед этим left и right вычисляются таким образом, что objectX это левый край. В таком случае симметрия формул непонятна. Можно [автора спросить](http://gamecodeschool.com/books/android-game-programming-by-example/)